# Edit editText according to selected button on Android?

Tags: android, android-button

In android, I have a method that browser file for my sdcard, 2 `Button` A and B and 2 `EditText` C and D.
I want when I click A, it browser file for my sdcard and edit C by selected file. And when I click B, it browser file and edit D by selected file also.

**How can I edit C and D according to selected button?**

Comment: So you want pressing A to open a file, place contents in C and then modifying the contents of the EditText C to modify the file contents? And the same with B/D?

Answer (score 1):

First, learn what is an ID in layout: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id

After then, you can get an edittext like:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditTextId);
```

Then you can change it using:

```
et.setText("Some text");
```

To execute some code after clicking a button you can use "onClick" parameter in XML:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents